# Setting conceallevel in .vimrc does not work in .tex file

Tags: vimrc, filetype-tex

I've set `conceallevel=0` in .vimrc, but the text is not shown normally after opening .tex file. I have to type it again while the file is open and it works.

From my .vimrc:

```
"vimtex config
set conceallevel=0
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:vimtex_view_method='zathura'
let g:tex_conceal = ''
let g:vimtex_fold_manual = 1
```

Comment: See [`:h 'conceallevel'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27conceallevel%27): `local to window` this means that setting it in your vimrc has no effect you need to set it either in a ftplugin or in an autocommand. I'm not posting an answer because I'm sure we have several duplicate about the same kind of issues.

Comment: You might want to check out [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604); in general, we do *not* need your whole vimrc in the post. A smaller example is better.

Comment: Sure, I edited it. Now it includes only these lines that are related to the problem.

Comment: You should mention explicitly that you use VimTeX. Note that, from VimTeX v2.0, the `g:tex_conceal` and `g:tex_flavor` are no longer relevant and will most likely do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

@statox, thank you! I've set two autocommands:

```
autocmd BufEnter *.tex set conceallevel=1
autocmd BufEnter *.tex set concealcursor=n
```

I've found this `concealcursor` feature, it seems useful to remove concealment of one line only when editing it. So I don't need `set conceallevel=0`.

I also removed `let g:tex_conceal = ''`, looks like it doesn't work.
[Info from the new release of vimtex:](https://newreleases.io/project/github/lervag/vimtex/release/v2.0)

> Vimtex no longer respects the "internal" options such as g:tex_fast and g:tex_conceal. For conceals, see :help g:vimtex_syntax_conceal.

Thanks again for not showing me the correct response, it forced me to search and learn more.

Comment: Did you check out `:help g:vimtex_syntax_conceal`? It looks to me that a simple `let g:vimtex_syntax_conceal_default = 0` would work to disable conceal on TeX files with the new vimtex. Maybe try that? And it looks like the new option gives you a very granular control of what to display and what to conceal, in case you're interested in using *some* of the concealing syntax but not all...

Comment: yes, setting ```let g:vimtex_syntax_conceal_default = 0``` in vimrc solves the original problem; looks like it's a simpler solution. But now I prefer to keep only ```autocmd BufEnter *.tex set concealcursor=c```. It removes concealment in the places where the cursor appears. It's very comfortable for me. I guess that setting ```g:vimtex_syntax_conceal_default``` in vimrc is not necessarily needed now because its default value works fine with the functionality of ```concealcursor```. Anyways, many thanks!